# Laravel 7 assigning foreignID using request->route('id)?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, view, controller

I'm trying to submit a form to a store function. The problem is, the foreignKey (degree_id) keeps being set to ?(null) even though I set it to the id in the route.

Form:

```
  {!! Form::open(['url' => 'degrees/{{ $Degree->id }}', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
                    <br>
                    {{Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>      'Title'])}}
                  </div>
                  @error('title')
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                  @enderror
```

Route:

```
Route::post('degrees/{degree}', 'ModuleController@store');
```

Store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'desc' => 'required',
        'long_desc' => 'required',
        'hours' => 'required',
        'credits'=> 'required',
      ]);

      $module = new Module;
      $module->title = $request->input('title');
      $module->desc = $request->input('desc');
      $module->long_desc = $request->input('long_desc');
      $module->hours = $request->input('hours');
      $module->credits = $request->input('credits');
      $module->degree_id = $request->route('id');
      $module->save();

      return redirect('/home/modules');


}
```

I've since set the degree_id to nullable, so I can create my module and have it display alright, but for future functionality I'd like it to be set to the degree_id. Any idea whats not working here? I do have model-relationships set up, but I can't see how that'd impact it. Maybe something in the route itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Blade Mustache inside a php element, use this instead:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'degrees/' . $Degree->id , 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route parameter is not named `id`, you declared it in your route definition as the name `degree` (`'degrees/{degree}'`).

```
$request->route('degree');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change route from

```
Route::post('degrees/{degree}', 'ModuleController@store');

                        TO

Route::post('degrees/{id}', 'ModuleController@store');
```